# Find previous object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    var arr = ["10/27/2017","11/5/2017","11/5/2017","11/10/2017","11/10/2017","12/12/2017"];
    var userDate = "11/10/2017";
```

If I want to find a date in this (assume sorted) array that is right before the user date, how would I do so? So in this case, I'd like to return `11/5/2017`.

Basically, finding the next closest object to the left of the designated date in the array. To take it one step further, if I wanted to then check again what the previous element was, but wanted to avoid duplicates, that would be helpful.

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf you just need to minus 1 from the result or just google how to find string in an array

Comment: To find dates inbetween try playing with this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gL97wq2q/ - I did not finish it but the code is there to be debugged

Comment: @mplungjan thanks I appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Don't forget to check if the element exists and isn't the first with `arr.indexOf(userDate) > 0`

```js
let arr = ["10/27/2017","11/5/2017","11/10/2017","11/10/2017","12/12/2017"];
let userDate = "11/10/2017";

let result = arr.indexOf(userDate) > 0 ? arr[arr.indexOf(userDate) - 1] : null;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why the downvote, though?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed someone is on a down-voting spree. Watched each new answer be immediately down-voted...

Comment: Either a bot, or someone is angry...

Comment: Mine was first but got two downvotes

Comment: im assuming the same, downvotes galore without reason

Comment: I upped this one because it was the first one to work when the date is at the first position

Comment: I think , for the people who downvote , comment should be made compulsory saying reason whey they are downvoting

Comment: They are likely downvoting us to punish us for answering a question that neded more investigation before being asked

Comment: I appreciate the help! I was over thinking it. I'll mark it checked it when it lets me

Comment: Every single answer assumes 'userDate' will always be in the array, rather than, for example, being '11/8/2017' -- it doesn't account for inbetween dates, which is more than likely what the original question wants.

Comment: Why are you calling `indexOf` twice? That's probably why you got downvoted. To be honest, I'm hesitant to downvote myself because of that.

Comment: @TKoL Mine tests that the date is NOT in the array. And why would we not assume there is no inbetween dates? The list could be a list of available dates and no other dates inbetween

Comment: @mplungjan Already upvoted.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Because I like one-liners. OP is free to store the index if he wants too :)

Comment: and thank you @Zenoo for the help thus far

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple using [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var arr = ["10/27/2017", "11/5/2017", "11/10/2017", "11/10/2017", "12/12/2017"];
var userDate = "11/10/2017";
var prev = arr.indexOf(userDate); // One call to indexOf - DRY
console.log(
   prev > 0 ? // neither the first (==0) nor not found (==-1)
   arr[prev-1] : "no earlier date"
);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could define some prototype methods on the array to seek a value given an optional; initial index. https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/quLe0tgd/

Comment: To test for inbetween, play with this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gL97wq2q/
I did not have time to finish it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to get the index of the date. And then it is easy to get the previous value.

Yo can try something as follows:

```js
var arr = ["10/27/2017","11/5/2017","11/10/2017","11/10/2017","12/12/2017"];
var userDate = "11/10/2017";
    
var index = arr.indexOf(userDate); // Get the index
var previous = index > 0 ? arr[index - 1] : null; // Check if the date exists. If it does exists get the previous value or set it to null
console.log(previous)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `indexOf` is the best for this problem.

```js
var arr = ["10/27/2017", "11/5/2017", "11/10/2017", "11/10/2017", "12/12/2017"];
var userDate = "11/10/2017";
var index = arr.indexOf(userDate);
var result = "";

if (index < 0) { // no match case
  result = 'no match';
} else if (index == 0) { // userdate is first element
  result = 'userDate is first element';
} else { // get the result
  result = arr[index - 1];
}
console.log('result=', result);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
arr[arr.indexOf(userData) - 1] ? arr[arr.indexOf(userData) - 1] : throw new Error('...');
```

If you insist. 
I would prefer handle the case that value is undefined when I'm actually using it.

Comment: Please add explanation and also handle that the date is not the first or not found

Answer (score -2):

```
var arr = ["10/27/2017","11/5/2017","11/10/2017","11/10/2017","12/12/2017"];

function findLeft(argum) {
  let firstIndex = arr.indexOf(argum);
  let leftside = firstIndex - 1;
  //you need to figure out error handling for < 0;

  return arr[leftside]; 
}
```

Comment: There is no invocation nor test for <=0

Comment: @mplungjan do you see the comment "you need error handling"?

im not sure what OPs error case is, and he/she should be able to add the error handling they require.